# Redux program - Output is not printed in VS Code terminal for below code. There are no errors but output is not printed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

[image]

```
const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_USERS_REQUEST'
const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS'
const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USERS_FAILURE'
```

Below code shows no error but it does not work. I dont see any mistakes here as i am new to Redux. So i request anyone to look into this and find out why output is not printed to console. There might be something very basic that i am missing here. Please check.please check image for remaining code.

```
//Reducer function
const reducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_USERS_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:true

            }
            case 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading:false,
                    users: action.payload,
                    error:''
    
                }
                case 'FETCH_USERS_FAILURE':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading:false,
                        users: [],
                        error:action.payload
        
                    }
                
        
    }

}
//common channel
const fetchUsers = () => {
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(fetchUsersRequest())
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
            const users = response.data.map(user => user.id)
            dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error.message))
        })
    }

}
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
console.log("Debugging")
store.subscribe(() => {console.log((store.getState()))})
console.log("post subscribe")
store.dispatch(fetchUsers)
```

Comment: Post more code. Include the whole reducer function and the definition of fetchUsers.

Comment: @Dylan Kerler I have added Dylan. Thanks. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is on this line:

```
store.dispatch(fetchUsers)
```

You must actually invoke the function like this to get it to work:

```
store.dispatch(fetchUsers())
```